# How do I use parallel processing for a function acting on a numpy array, when part of the function is to add rows to the array and keep updating it?

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing

The code I have below functions perfectly fine.

But what I want to change is: if the "variable" I have is greater than 0, I want to add a row, for example [0,1,0,0], to the existing array, and then have the function and parallel processing work on this updated array.

I wrote down the code I've already tried below.

I get the error message: "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2".

The message also says this is a direct cause of this line:

master_array = np.vstack((pool.map(third_three_part_function, array)))

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

array = np.zeros((4, 4))
for i in range(np.size(array,1)):
    array[i,0] = 10

def third_three_part_function(array):
    for i in range(np.size(array) - 1):     
        variable = (np.random.poisson( 1, 1))       
        array[i+1] =array[i ]+ variable     
    return(array)

from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    master_array = np.vstack((pool.map(third_three_part_function, array)))
    print(master_array)

#### What I've already tried, but doesn't work:
    for i in range(np.size(array) - 1):     
            variable = (np.random.poisson( 1, 1))       
            array[i+1] =array[i ]+ variable 
        if variable>0:
                addition = [0,1,0,0]
                array = np.vstack([array,addition])
    return(array)
```

The goal is that for each new row I add to the array, the function and parallel processing also works on those new rows, as opposed to only the original rows of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Pool.map` to run a function over an array, your function is run in parallel in two processes (in this case). Each of these two processes has a *copy* of `array`.

Whatever you do to the array in one process *does not change* the array in the other process! Nor does it influence the array in the parent process that calls `Pool.map`!

So for a `Pool.map` to work properly, your worker function has to take a single argument (this can be a list or tuple, though). It works on that argument and then *returns a result*. The `multiprocessing` module then sends this result back to the parent process. All these return values are gathered in a list and returned by `Pool.map`.

For example, suppose you want to count the number of words in files.
You call `Pool.map` with a worker function and a list of file names.
The worker function takes a single filename as an argument. It reads that file, count the words and returns the number of words in that file.
So `Pool.map` returns a list of word counts, corresponding to the list of file names given.

**Edit**: If you are not bound to `numpy` arrays, you could use shared memory in the form of a `multiprocessing.Array`.
But you need to think about how to use this. When you create such an array you can specify if it should be protected with a lock (which is the default). This wil serialize access to the array and prevent memory corruption, but it will show things down. The other option is to not use a lock. But in that case, *you* have to prevent memory corruption.

For example, say you have an array of 100 numbers, and you want to use two processes. Then you should program your worker function to take an offset argument. The first worker gets offset 0, and only works on array elements 0 to 49. The second worker gets offset 50 and only works on elments 50 to 99.
If you do it like this, you should be able to use shared memory without locks and without memory corruption.

Comment: Thanks, so if I can't use Pool.map, is there another function that will let me parallel process the way I'm trying to?